# How can I list all table in my database and be able use the results to preform functions in Electron or NodeJs

Tags: mysql, node.js, electron

I am trying to create an app where I will be able to list all tables in my database and then when the tables are listed. I want to be able to click each table and it should display all columns of the clicked table in electron or node js.

for example, If I have a database called 'students' and this database has about 3 tables namely 'table1' 'table2' and 'table3' and each table has its own 2 columns that have 'id' and 'name'

so say I want to list all these tables and then if I click on table1 it should take me to table1 and Select all my columns to display.

I have this code below and it helps display the tables but I have no clue of how can I make it perform based on which table I clicked.

````
<html lang="en">
<head>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css">
    
</head>
<body>
   
<br>
<br>
         
    <div class="container">

    <table class="table table-striped " >
       
            <tr>
                <th>Grades </th>
            </tr>
            <tr id="grades">
                
            </tr>
        
    </table>
    </div>


<script type="text/javascript">



var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
        host     : "localhost",
  user     : "root",
  password : "",
  database : "students"
});



con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('connected');


  var sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM students "

  con.query(sql, function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw Eerr ;

  
        var i;
for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

var cls = document.getElementById("grades"); 
var list ="<div>"+ result[i].Tables_in_students + "</div><br>";


cls.innerHTML += list;
    


}


});
 

});


</script>


</body>
</html>```
````

Comment: It's a big topic, possibly too big for a Stack Overflow answer. Hint: in MySQL, take a look at the built-in [`information_schema`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema.html) database, especially the [TABLES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-tables-table.html) and [COLUMNS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-columns-table.html) pseudo-tables. They describe the actual tables on the server.

Comment: After you click the table, it display all columns, then what is the next operation? Does it end there? Are you just looking to display table columns or are you going to use it for some other operation? Probably something like a customize reports where you can select which column to display and such? IF you only want to show the table structures, pre-load all of them to the app and hide each table structure using something like [accordion](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp) etc.

Comment: Okay, thanks, O.Jones. FanoFN yes I want to be able to click on each div and it should perform based on it's innerHTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if the code is structured right but this code works exactly how I wanted it. and I believe I may have made an unnecessary second connection.

So here's how it works, the code below loops through my database and displays them in my table and I made a trick of loop-adding buttons and set values of those buttons to the name of the table. So that I can later use it to call functions.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
        host     : "localhost",
  user     : "root",
  password : "",
  database : "students"
});



con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('connected');

 }); 



  
var tableContent = document.getElementById("tableContent"); 
tableContent.innerHTML = "";
  var sql = "SHOW TABLES  " ;

  con.query(sql, function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    


     var i;
    for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    
    var num =result[i].Tables_in_students;

var list ="<tr><td><button value="+num+" onclick='deletorr(this)'></button></td></tr>";

tableContent.innerHTML += list;


}

});
```

Then I have a function deletorr() which checks the value of the button.
Each button has a value of a table name that it's associated with. If that button is clicked, the function will delete the table along with the button. As shown below.

```
function deletorr(sel){

     var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
        host     : "localhost",
  user     : "root",
  password : "",
  database : "students"
});



con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('connected');


 }); 

    
    
    var value = sel.value;
    var sql = "DROP TABLE " +value;

 con.query(sql, function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) alert (err);

  

        
});

// refresh page and show instant result after deleting table
location.reload();

}
```